# How to handle my code when different jQuery object names are possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin

I have a simple function that I'd like to run on `$.ready`. The same function should run both on the frontend as well as on the admin pages.

Problem happens on the admin pages because there the `jQuery` variable is not defined. Instead they define `django.jQuery`.

How can I make my code fit both cases without polluting global namespace with an additional `jQuery` name?

This is what I have so far, it works, but leaves the additional `jQuery` name in global scope:

```
if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined' && typeof django !== 'undefined') {
   jQuery = django.jQuery;
}
jQuery(function($){...});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what the big deal with having jQuery in the global namespace. BUT you can do something like this:

```
(function (jQuery) { 
    jQuery(function($){...});
})(window.jQuery || django.jQuery));
```

or more confusing

```
(window.jQuery || django.jQuery)(jQuery(function($){...});
```